# Resource url in a dojo call not mapping to annotated class in controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, model-view-controller, dojo

I have an issue with resource mapping.

My controller-

```
@ResourceMapping("AccountConfirm")
    public void suspendServiceRequest(ResourceRequest request,ResourceResponse response, @ModelAttribute ServiceModel model, ModelMap modelMap) 
              throws CommonServiceException{        

        System.out.println("<<<<<<<<I ENTERED THE ACCOUNT>>>>>>");
}
```

I need to reach this method in my controller when the confirm button in my JSP is clicked.
JSP snipet where this fuction is supposed to be called -

```
 <button class="footer-btn" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" type="button" id = "confirmButton" >
      Confirm
    </button>
```

I am making an ajax call and I am using the following JS code for it

```
function confirmFunction() {

                var confirmURL = '<%=renderResponse.encodeURL(AccountConfirm.toString())%>';

                alert("entered confirm function ");

                var xhrArgs = {
                    url: confirmURL,
                    handleAs: "json",
                    load: function(data){
                        if(data==null){
                         alert("Data not sent");
                                     }
                         if(data!=null){
                        alert("Data Received");

                        //performs some function

                   }
                 }
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log("ERROR ERROR");
                }
              };

           }
```

on CLicking the button, my function does not display the `alert("Data Received");` or the error message. I don't know where I am going wrong. Please help.